# Run PyQt project on multiple computers

Tags: python, pyqt

I've built my app with PyQt, since in my python code I have `import PyQt4` the code won't work unless you have Pyqt installed on your computer. Is there a way to pack PyQt in the same folder as my python program so it will work on every computer that has python installed, or some other way (without .exe).

Comment: How are you installing your app on the other computers?

Comment: A tool for creating isolated Python environments is vitualenv. This is to have all packages you need, so you can develop independently from the current installed python. I used Pyinstaller to create a windows exe. It's quite similar to virtualenv. Read about it? Here is an overview: https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @BrendanAbel I'm not installing it, i'm sending it as .py script., I don't want .exe, I want it to be in .py format

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making an installer package for your python file.

First, you have to install the `pyinstaller` package. If you have `python` and `pip` installed on your computer you can open your Terminal/Command Prompt and enter like this

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

and press Enter. It'll take about a few seconds to install. If the installation is complete, `cd` to the directory where your python file exists. And enter this into the Terminal/Command Prompt

```
pyinstaller --onefile your_python_file.py
```

This might take a couple of minutes to build your `.exe` file. Now you will see some new files and folders created. If you open the `dist` folder you will find your `.exe` file, take that file out of the `dist` folder and keep it with your python file and folders. Now compress your python `.py` file and the `pyinstaller` files and folders (like `dist` and `build`) including the `.exe` file.

After this, you can install a software called NSIS. Click [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download) to open the installation page. Open the software after installation. In that, under **Compiler**, click on the option that says ***Installer based on .ZIP file***. Click open in the new window and select the file that was compressed earlier. Give a name for your installer, select a path for **OUTPUT EXE file** and leave the other options as default and click **Generate**. It'll take some time to generate. If that is done then your installer is ready.

Share the installer `.exe` file with your friends and family and show off your skills.

Good Luck .

If any of these steps didn't work, please leave a comment and I will try my best to answer those.

> If you don't have `python` and `pip` installed click this [link](https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/)